# Contacts App in Marshmallow does not pull contacts from all accounts

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, moto-x

I have a Moto X Pure Edition running Marshmallow. I have multiple accounts set up such as Messenger, Skype, WhatsApp, Outlook etc. However, even though I have chosen "Show all contacts" option in the Contacts App, the list is only filled with a few Google contacts and Skype contacts. I am unable to see any of the Messenger or Exchange Contacts. If I go to the Outlook app which is synced with the Exchange account, I am able to see the contacts.

I would very much appreciate it if I could get some assistance.

Thanks
SV